# WPF field is null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have private field

```
private DateTime? StartTime;
```

I am setting that field on button click

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

But when i am accessing that field from EventHandler

```
private void InitTimers()
        {
            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

            dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            lbTodayDate.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            if(StartTime != null) //Always null
                lbElipsedTime.Content = DateTime.Now - StartTime;

            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
```

`StartTime` always remains `null`

May be someone could explain that?

`InitTimmers` getting called inside public `MainWindow()` default constructor when program starts.

Button click fires, timer ticking, I've checked that.
On button click `StartTime` initialized to `DateTime.Now`, so it is not equal to null, but on timer tick it is equal to null. Just for test i set `StartTime` inside intimidate window so it is became not null and expression  `if(StartTime != null)` not `false` any more

**UPDATE**

Ok I've done something stupid, i am running asynchronous method, the key is there:

```
 private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                DoAsyncMethod(); //should do StartTime = null inside.
                StartTime = null
            }
```

I should do `StartTime = null` inside async method, that is it, thank you guys.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your button click code is executed?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your button's code to see whether it fires.

Comment: Yes, have you tried setting a breakpoints on that line (`StartTime = DateTime.Now;`)?

Comment: You forgot to click on that button? Hehehehe

Comment: what about `if(StartTime != null)`? have you tried setting a breakpoint there to make sure the timer has been started?

Comment: Button click fires, timer ticking, I've checked that.

Comment: Are you sure that there is only *one*  `StartTime` field (it's not a property!) and that all of the code you showed us is in the same class?

Comment: We can't determine the problem using the information you've given. I'd suggest placing a `Debug.WriteLine("a")` in your click handler, and the same thing with a different message in your tick handler. This way you can see that the events are in fact firing, and the order that they are running in.

Comment: :facepalm: This is why you need to give us all the code.

Comment: @Kendall Frey exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint in the `DispatcherTimer_Tick` and the `btnStart_Click` handlers, you will probably find that the `DispatcherTimer_Tick` handler is called first... therefore the `StartTime` property would not have been set yet.

If you're saying that even after consecutive `Button` clicks, the value is *still* `null`, then either you are setting it to `null` somewhere else, or your `btnStart_Click` handler is *not* called... are you sure that it is wired up correctly?

Comment: Yes you right `DispatcherTimer_Tick` fires first. But why after `btnStart_Click` value `StartTime` still remaining `null` inside `DispatcherTimer_Tick` ? Are they accessing to different instances ? I am not setting `StartTime` somewhere else

Comment: Put a break point in the handler... does it ever break in there? If it does, does the `StartTime` field get set?

Answer (score 3):

I've just used this code in a test app and it works OK. Adding the code here for your comparison:

[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DateTime? StartTime;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitTimers(); 
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void InitTimers()
        {
            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

            dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (StartTime != null) //Always null
                lbElipsedTime.Content = DateTime.Now - StartTime;

            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
    }
}
```